# Can't add app to Site Contents

Tags: office-365, app

After uploading a new version of an app to the app catalogue, I was expecting to see the new version reflected in my web part. When I didn't, I deleted the web part and re-added it. I still didn't see the new version so I deleted the app from the app catalogue and uploaded it again. After doing this I found I could no longer add the app to my site collection.

When I click Add on the My Apps page it says it has been added but when I go to Site Contents it is not there. When I refresh the My Apps page it does not appear under Added Apps.

It says in the app catalogue that the app is valid, enabled & deployed (not tenant deployed).

I've tried deleting it from the app catalogue and the recycle bin and uploading it again but the problem remains.

Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

N.B. I should mention I can add the app to another site collection and I can add other apps to this site collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by changing the solution guid

Comment: You can mark your response as an answer & add more detailed step if possible. So that this will help other users in future with similar problem.

Comment: A new guid can be generated in Visual Studio via TOOLS - Create GUID. It needs to be changed in a few places, an easy way is to search with 'Find in Files' in Visual Studio Code